# How do I check if a script is running and pause until that instance has completed to run again?

Tags: bash, shell-script

So we run this script that adds data to a file and I'm trying to add something to check and see if the script is already running. If so, then I want it to pause and check again in 20s and repeat that until it finds it not running. At which point, I'd like it to proceed to the rest of the script. So I need to know how to have it keep checking until its okay to proceed. Anyone have an idea?

````
    if [ `ps -ef| grep $script_name_with_arguments | wc -l ` -gt 1 ]
    then
      echo "already running"
      sleep 20s
    else
      echo "ok"
    fi
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You use some kind of locking.

The simplest way is a lockfile.  There are a few packages that will manage those for you; you did not say what your platform or distro was so I cannot be super precise about that, but one of them is the `procmail` package which comes with the `lockfile` program.

You'd use it in your script like this:

```
LOCK=/run/npaulsen/mylockfile.lock
lockfile -20 $LOCK
run_the_fscking_rest_of_my_script
rm -f $LOCK
```

There are refinements you can do to avoid it being stuck indefinitely in case one instance crashes.  You can read the manpage about that: `man 1 lockfile`.  Or you can implement your own - it is trivial but you'll need a real programming language (not a shell script).

Another more sophisticated (but also more complex) idea would be to use POSIX semaphores; try `man 7 sem_overview`.